# How to reset Identity Column Of Table when a record is deleted?

Tags: datagridview, ado.net, vb.net-2010, sqlcommandbuilder

I have a Datagridview which gets populated with some data from SQL Server. This works fine no problem at all.

Each time I insert or update records in the table, I want to RESEED an `IDENTITY` column named `CarID` of a table, but the sequence of IDS appears not good because sometimes records are deleted.

In my code, I use 'SQLCOMMANDBUILDER' to perform an insert ,update or delete
operations.

I have tried the following code below  but i throws an exception error which says "Cannot find table 0."

Where should I fix ??

```
//THESE ARE CODE TO RESEED AN IDENTITY COLUMN

Sub ResetIDColumn()
    Try
        Dim querystring As String = "declare @max int " &
                        "Select @max=max([CarID]) FROM [dbo].[Cars]" &
                        "if @max IS NULL SET @max = 0 " &
                        "DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[Cars]', RESEED,@max)"
        ds = New DataSet
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(querystring, con)
        cmdbuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
        da.Fill(ds)
        DgvCarList.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

 //CODE TO PUPOLATE DATAGRIDVIEW
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim querystring As String = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Cars]"
        ds = New DataSet
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(querystring, con)
        cmdbuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
        da.Fill(ds)
        DgvCarList.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

//CODE TO INSERT OR UPDATE DATA

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    ResetIDColumn()
    Try
        da.Update(ds.Tables(0))
        MessageBox.Show("Update was successful!", "Data")
        Loaddata()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

//CODE TO LOAD DATA 
Sub Loaddata()
    Dim querystring As String = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Cars]"
    ds = New DataSet
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(querystring, con)
    cmdbuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Fill(ds)
    DgvCarList.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    DgvCarList.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
End Sub
```

Comment: One word: ***DON'T DO THIS!*** You're just **asking** for trouble long term. Once an identity has been used - it's gone - **DO NOT** attempt to "recycle" it - that's not the way it works, and that's only going to cause you grief and trouble. Just leave identity values as they are and move on to real issues......

Comment: @marc_s that's actually 3 words (well, a lot more now...), but it is still the best advice someone could give the OP.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: okay - that's just being nit-picky :D

Comment: @marc_s of course, we are programmers, after all... if we wouldn't be nit-picky, who will?

Comment: @Mligo The point of an identity column is that it's auto-generated. You should not mess with it's values nor you should care what they are. If the values of a column have business meaning then that column should not be an identity column.

Comment: @ZoharPeled ofcourse i know about the restrictions concerning identity columns but i want that column IDS propery formated just for reporting.

Comment: I would suggest using a computed column instead of messing the id values.

Answer (score 0):

I tried harder and harder and finally I discovered that-;

1. You need to create a new  dataset,Sqlcommandbuilder and new dataadapter then query
   data from your table (using select statement) at the same time execute command to 
   reset id using 'single querystring'.
2. The aim of executing two command    is such that all the results are stored in SINGLE 
   DATASET
3. I decided to Call this sub after a record is deleted from table.

CODE:

```
// Button click to delete a record
 Try
        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim rowposition As Integer = DgvCarList.CurrentRow.Index
            Dim rowdelete As DataRow = ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowposition)
            rowdelete.Delete()
            da.Update(ds)
            MessageBox.Show("Delete was success!", "Data")
            Loaddata()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

  // After delete completed Go and reset an identity column 
    ResetIDColumn()


  // code to reset an identity column
 Sub ResetIDColumn()
    Try
        Dim querystring As String = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Cars] go " &
                                     "DECLARE @max INT " &
                        "Select @max=max([CarID]) FROM [dbo].[Cars]" &
                        "if @max IS NULL SET @max = 0 " &
                        "DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[Cars]', RESEED,@max)"
        ds = New DataSet
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(querystring, con)
        cmdbuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
        da.Fill(ds)
        DgvCarList.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub


          ...................Thank you all..................................
```